# Read from nth row from a csv file in php

Tags: php, csv

This is my CSV file

```
1,100003,cs1aa,abc1
2,100004,cs1aa,abc2
3,100008,cs1aa,abc3
4,100009,cs1aa,abc4
5,100010,cs1aa,abc5
6,100011,cs1aa,abc6
7,100012,cs1aa,abc7
8,100013,cs1aa,abc8
9,100014,cs1aa,abc9
10,100015,cs1aa,abc10
```

Now i m using fgetcsv in while loop to read my csv files

```
 $file = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
 while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
}
```

Is there a way in php to read this csv file from the nth line of the file ?
For eg, if n=5, then the loop should start reading from the 5th line of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate and run fgets as many times as you need to.

```php
<?php
$skip = 5;

$file = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
for($i = 0; $i < $skip && (fgets($tmp) !== false); $i++);
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
}
```

`fgets` reads a single line from the file.

Using `fgets` means you won't spend any additional time parsing CSV when you don't need to.

Comment: I like this one a lot, with the single caveat that one must be absolutely certain that interior data __doesn't__ contain a line ending, such as in a quoted string. It appear that the OP's data doesn't, so this is probably the most performant.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$skip = 5;
$c = 1;

$file = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    if( $c++ < $skip ) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is a viable solution, but what if my file got a million rows and i want to start from - say from 100 thousandth line, then i should skip through first 100 thousand lines in my loop., is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: No. Lines in a CSV are of an arbitrary length and there's no way to skip around without passing over the entire file. You could pre-create an index that maps line numbers to positions in the file and move the cursor around, but at that point you're beginning to re-invent a database.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected

```
$row = 0;
$start_from = 5; //starts from nth row, 5th row in this case

if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;

        //skip if value less than $start_from row value
        if($row<$start_from){
            continue;
        }
        //else print, you can also do something else with this data
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Explanation

1. Set a starting point
2. Skip the loop for as many rows as you want to skip
3. Keep the data after look, for demo I have used `for` loop but you can use whatever is your use case.